# Aligning a toolbar with search text box using font awesome

Tags: html, css, flexbox, font-awesome

I am trying a make a toolbar using font awesome with a few icons and search text box at the start.

I would like this to be ideally aligned in a way that it has search on the left most followed by the icons to its right.

```css
.icon-bar {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
  display:flex;

}

.icon-bar a {
  width: 15%;
  padding: 12px 0;
  float: left;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

#filtersubmit {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -25px;
  top: 1px;
  color: #7B7B7B;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <div class="icon-bar">
    <input id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="Search" /><i id="filtersubmit" class="fa fa-search"></i>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
    <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Ideally I would like to be aligned like this image below:

[image]

Changes as per the solution below:

Menu with full browser screen:

[image]

Now when I minimize the browser the scroll comes which is because of overflow:auto.

[image]

Is their a way I can control the width of the search box for the icons I think changing the fontsize does the trick.

Comment: there is no such thing as `position: left`

Comment: Thanks @dippas . I just got the fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add display flex to the .icon-bar div.

```
.icon-bar {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
display:flex;
}
```

Also, as dipas noted remove that position left.

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly fine as i was expecting it to. But I am not able to control the width of the search box. So in cases when I minimize the browser a scroll comes at the bottom.

Comment: If you don't want the scroll, remove overflow auto. And you can control the width of the input as .icon-bar input {width: 100%;} or whatever you need.

Comment: Also, don't forget that when you are on smaller screens you might want .icon-bar section to span the whole width. If you are on the phone that 30% width will be too small.

Comment: is there a way I can attach images here in comments to show the images on how it looks if I keep the overflow or remove it.

Comment: I don't think so. You could get some kind of screenshot app like Jing or something similar.

Comment: I did add the screenshots in the question at the bottom itself as i didnt see a place here . I would like to understand how to control the size for the search box alone and the icons I can handle by adjusting the font size in icon bar a.

Answer (score 3):

It is easier using `inline-block`s:

```css
.icon-bar {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
}
.icon-bar a {
  padding: 12px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 36px;
}
.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
#filtersubmit {
  color: #7B7B7B;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.icon-bar > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <div class="icon-bar">
    <input id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="Search" /><i id="filtersubmit" class="fa fa-search"></i>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
    <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>

  </div>
</div>
```

You can use `flexbox`es too:

```css
.icon-bar {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 60%;
}
.icon-bar a {
  padding: 12px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 36px;
}
.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
#filtersubmit {
  color: #7B7B7B;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <div class="icon-bar">
    <input id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="Search" /><i id="filtersubmit" class="fa fa-search"></i>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
    <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: table` on parent `.icon-bar` and `display: table-cell` on children groups `.search-bar` and `.button-wrapper`

```css
.icon-bar {
  display: table;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
}

.search-bar, .button-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#filtersubmit {
  color: #7B7B7B;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button-wrapper a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.button-wrapper a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <div class="icon-bar">
    <div class="search-bar">
      <input id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
      <i id="filtersubmit" class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
      <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```